# PHP Function creating a link at bottom in Footer

Tags: php, css, wordpress, encoding, base64

I am using a widget licence under GPL and want to remove the footer link.

you can see the link showing here

http://www.emortgagecalculator.org

and please advice how to edit this function to remove the link

```
function mcalc_init() {
    // $code = 'PGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5rZXlzdG9uZWF1dG9sb2Fucy5jb20iPmF1dG8gbG9hbnM8L2E+;PGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5rZXlzdG9uZWF1dG9sb2Fucy5jb20vYmFkLWNyZWRpdC1hdXRvLWxvYW5zLyI+YmFkIGNyZWRpdCBhdXRvIGxvYW5zPC9hPg==;PGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5rZXlzdG9uZWF1dG9sb2Fucy5jb20vYmFkLWNyZWRpdC1hdXRvLWxvYW5zLyI+YmFkIGNyZWRpdCBjYXIgbG9hbnM8L2E+;PGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5rZXlzdG9uZWF1dG9sb2Fucy5jb20vdXNlZC1hdXRvLWxvYW5zLyI+dXNlZCBjYXIgYXV0byBsb2FuczwvYT4=;PGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5rZXlzdG9uZWF1dG9sb2Fucy5jb20vdXNlZC1hdXRvLWxvYW5zLyI+dXNlZCBjYXIgbG9hbnM8L2E+;PGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5rZXlzdG9uZWF1dG9sb2Fucy5jb20vdXNlZC1hdXRvLWxvYW5zLyI+dXNlZCBhdXRvIGxvYW5zPC9hPg==;PGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5rZXlzdG9uZWF1dG9sb2Fucy5jb20vdXNlZC1hdXRvLWxvYW5zLyI+dXNlZCBjYXIgbG9hbjwvYT4=;PGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5rZXlzdG9uZWF1dG9sb2Fucy5jb20vbmV3LWF1dG8tbG9hbnMvIj5uZXcgY2FyIGF1dG8gbG9hbnM8L2E+;PGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5jYXJsb2Fud2l0aG5vY3JlZGl0LmNvbSI+Y2FyIGxvYW4gd2l0aCBubyBjcmVkaXQ8L2E+;PGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5jYXJsb2Fud2l0aG5vY3JlZGl0LmNvbSI+YXV0byBsb2FuIHdpdGggbm8gY3JlZGl0PC9hPg==;PGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5jYXJsb2Fud2l0aG5vY3JlZGl0LmNvbSI+Y2FyIGxvYW5zIHdpdGggbm8gY3JlZGl0PC9hPg==;PGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5jYXJsb2Fud2l0aG5vY3JlZGl0LmNvbSI+YXV0byBsb2FucyB3aXRoIG5vIGNyZWRpdDwvYT4=;PGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5jYXJsb2Fud2l0aG5vY3JlZGl0LmNvbSI+bm8gY3JlZGl0IGNhciBsb2FuczwvYT4=;PGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5jYXJsb2Fud2l0aG5vY3JlZGl0LmNvbSI+bm8gY3JlZGl0IGF1dG8gbG9hbnM8L2E+';
    $code = "PGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5yZXBhaWQub3JnIj5SZXBhaWQub3JnPC9hPg==";
    $init = explode(';',$code);
    $loan_init = rand(0,sizeof($init)-1);
    update_option('loan_init', base64_decode($init[$loan_init]));
    update_option('mc_footer_color', '#999');
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in footer in your given link.

Comment: see the calculator widget footer there is link powered by repaid.org and above function in generating it with base64 code..

Comment: You can replace it with base64 equivalent of empty string. See my answer for more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace link with `&nbsp;` and base64 equivalent of this is `Jm5ic3A7`, so you can use;

```
function mcalc_init() {
    $code = "Jm5ic3A7";
    $init = explode(';',$code);
    $loan_init = rand(0,sizeof($init)-1);
    update_option('loan_init', base64_decode($init[$loan_init]));
    update_option('mc_footer_color', '#999');
}
```

Or you can try;

```
function mcalc_init() {
    $init = explode(';',$code);
    $loan_init = rand(0,sizeof($init)-1);
    update_option('loan_init', "&nbsp;"); // Or put anything you want
    update_option('mc_footer_color', '#999');
}
```

**Update:** Second option worked for OP (just for incoming users)

Comment: Thanks huseyin...2nd option work for me..by adding the code function is disable and then i removed the link from footer thanks...

Comment: Also, `update_option` put record in db with a key `loan_init`. You can set it to empty from db also ;)

Comment: how i can do that also please explain little bit

Comment: @user2326082 `UPDATE wp_options SET option_value="" WHERE option_name="loan_init"` Is this clear? There is a table in wp system called `wp_options`. While you are developing plugin, theme in wp, sometimes you need to store some settings in db. This is the table you stored your settings of specific components

Answer (score 0):

First of all find the `action` hook,

Hook will be something like this:-

```
add_action('HOOK_NAME', 'mcalc_init');
```

Now add this in your `theme's functions.php` or `plugin's main file` file:-

```
remove_action('HOOK_NAME', 'mcalc_init');
add_action('HOOK_NAME', 'my_mcalc_init');
function my_mcalc_init()
{
    // $code = 'PGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5rZXlzdG9uZWF1dG9sb2Fucy5jb20iPmF1dG8gbG9hbnM8L2E+;PGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5rZXlzdG9uZWF1dG9sb2Fucy5jb20vYmFkLWNyZWRpdC1hdXRvLWxvYW5zLyI+YmFkIGNyZWRpdCBhdXRvIGxvYW5zPC9hPg==;PGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5rZXlzdG9uZWF1dG9sb2Fucy5jb20vYmFkLWNyZWRpdC1hdXRvLWxvYW5zLyI+YmFkIGNyZWRpdCBjYXIgbG9hbnM8L2E+;PGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5rZXlzdG9uZWF1dG9sb2Fucy5jb20vdXNlZC1hdXRvLWxvYW5zLyI+dXNlZCBjYXIgYXV0byBsb2FuczwvYT4=;PGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5rZXlzdG9uZWF1dG9sb2Fucy5jb20vdXNlZC1hdXRvLWxvYW5zLyI+dXNlZCBjYXIgbG9hbnM8L2E+;PGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5rZXlzdG9uZWF1dG9sb2Fucy5jb20vdXNlZC1hdXRvLWxvYW5zLyI+dXNlZCBhdXRvIGxvYW5zPC9hPg==;PGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5rZXlzdG9uZWF1dG9sb2Fucy5jb20vdXNlZC1hdXRvLWxvYW5zLyI+dXNlZCBjYXIgbG9hbjwvYT4=;PGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5rZXlzdG9uZWF1dG9sb2Fucy5jb20vbmV3LWF1dG8tbG9hbnMvIj5uZXcgY2FyIGF1dG8gbG9hbnM8L2E+;PGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5jYXJsb2Fud2l0aG5vY3JlZGl0LmNvbSI+Y2FyIGxvYW4gd2l0aCBubyBjcmVkaXQ8L2E+;PGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5jYXJsb2Fud2l0aG5vY3JlZGl0LmNvbSI+YXV0byBsb2FuIHdpdGggbm8gY3JlZGl0PC9hPg==;PGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5jYXJsb2Fud2l0aG5vY3JlZGl0LmNvbSI+Y2FyIGxvYW5zIHdpdGggbm8gY3JlZGl0PC9hPg==;PGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5jYXJsb2Fud2l0aG5vY3JlZGl0LmNvbSI+YXV0byBsb2FucyB3aXRoIG5vIGNyZWRpdDwvYT4=;PGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5jYXJsb2Fud2l0aG5vY3JlZGl0LmNvbSI+bm8gY3JlZGl0IGNhciBsb2FuczwvYT4=;PGEgaHJlZj0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy5jYXJsb2Fud2l0aG5vY3JlZGl0LmNvbSI+bm8gY3JlZGl0IGF1dG8gbG9hbnM8L2E+';
    $code = "";
    $init = explode(';',$code);
    $loan_init = rand(0,sizeof($init)-1);
    update_option('loan_init', base64_decode($init[$loan_init]));
    update_option('mc_footer_color', '#999');
}
```

OR You can hide this part with css also like this:-

Add this in `theme's header file`.

```
<style>
.mc-container .mc-footer{display:none;}
</style>
```

Hope this will will work.